# Nested CloudFormation - Child template not picking up Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am building a nested CloudFormation template to build an EKS cluster, node group and associated roles. IAM stack builds just fine, when it begins the Cluster stack its failing with the following error; "Parameters: [IAMRoleARN] do not exist in the template".

Within the IAM stack, I've defined an Output/Export for the created role ARN;

```
 Outputs:
    ClusterRoleArn:
      Value: !GetAtt ClusterRole.Arn
      Description: EKS cluster role ARN
      Export:
        Name: 
          Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-ClusterRoleArn"
```

In my parent stack, I'm importing the export as part of my parameters for the Cluster child stack;

```
EksClusterStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: '{bucket name withheld}'
      Parameters:
        EksVpc: !Ref EksStackVpc
        ClusterName: !Ref EksClusterName
        IAMRoleARN:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - EksIamStack
            - Outputs.ClusterRoleArn
        VpcSecurityGroup: !Ref EksVpcSecurityGroup
        ClusterSubnet1: !Ref EksSubnet1
        ClusterSubnet2: !Ref EksSubnet2
```

In the Cluster child stack, I have a top level parameter set up, that I then call on in the resources section;

```
Parameters:
  IAMRoleARN:
    Type: String
    Description: ARN of the IAM role created for the cluster in the 
                 EKS IAM stack

Cluster:
  Type: "AWS::EKS::Cluster"
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref ClusterName
    Version: "1.19"
    RoleArn: !Ref IAMRoleARN
    ResourcesVpcConfig:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
        - !Ref VpcSecurityGroup
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref ClusterSubnet1
        - !Ref ClusterSubnet2
```

Any ideas on what I may be missing is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the whole resources always and the whole sections like parameters etc? Otherwise it is really confusing

Comment: Updated with more information from each of the stacks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to export your ARN cross stack, your output should look like this:

```
Outputs:
    ClusterRoleArn:
      Value: !GetAtt ClusterRole.Arn
```

Otherwise you would have to import it with

```
Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ClusterRoleArn
```